# Show that $x^2-10y^2=\pm 5$ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i want to show $x^2-10y^2=5 \text{ or } -5$ has no solutions over $\Bbb Z$. how can i show it? no clear method comes to my mind. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try plugging in arbitrary even and odd values and looking at the congruence mod 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
x^2-10y^2=\pm5&\implies x^2-0\equiv 0\bmod 5\\
&\implies x^2\equiv 0\bmod 5\\
&\implies x\equiv 0\bmod 5\\
&\implies x^2\equiv 0\bmod 25
\end{align*}$$
Thus, we have
$$\begin{align*}
-10y^2\equiv \pm 5\bmod 25&\implies -2y^2\equiv \pm 1\bmod 5\\
&\implies 2y^2\equiv 1\text{ or }4\bmod 5
\end{align*}$$
But the possible values of $2y^2$ modulo $5$ are $0,2,3$.

Comment: this is neat. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 5 must divide $2y^2+1$ or $2y^2-1$ which is not possible because squares mod 5 are in $\{0,1,-1\}
$.